# I want my dropdown menu to have a max-width, but my CSS isn't working as expected

Tags: html, css

I want my dropdown menus to be no more than 250px wide, and the text to wrap to the next line. I set a max-width but they are not expanding.

http://jsfiddle.net/wtpvejjh/1/

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a>First
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">I want this to wrap to the next line at 250px</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>Second
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>Third
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: max-width will work only for those element whose with will be greater than 250. if you want to set fix with then you have to use width attribute.

Comment: I don't want a fixed width, I want it to get wider with the text up to 250px, and then wrap to the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To restrict the specific LI (as per OP's original question):**

Set the `nav ul {width:250px}` and `clear` the floated `li`'s. They'll then sit below eachother and will only be as wide as their content up until they are as wide as the parent (250px) and are forced to wrap.

```css
nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}

nav li a {
  display:inline-block; /* Make these inline or inline block so their width is collapsed. */
}

nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px; /* Set width. This will 'contain' the children. */
}

nav li ul li {
   clear:both; /* Clear these so they stack. */
}
nav li ul li a {
  padding: 5px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a>First
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">I want this to wrap to the next line at 250px</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>Second
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>Third
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

**To restrict the child UL to a max-width (as per OP's comment):**

It feels a bit 'hacky' and your mileage may vary but the following works for me...

Use `inline-block` rather than `float`ing the parent `li`'s. Set the child `ul` to the desired max `width` and present the child `li`s as `table-rows`. This should mean that the *'table-row'* will be collapsed and held open by the content up until it reaches its parent's bounds - at which point the content will wrap.

```css
nav {
  font-size:0; /* set font size to avoid the natural margin that exists between inline-block elements */
}
nav li {
  font-size:16px; /* undo font size change to avoid the natural margin that exists between inline-block elements */
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block; /* display inline (rather than float) */
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav li:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
nav li a {
  display:block;
}
nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:250px; /* fix at your desired max width */
}
nav li ul li {
  display:table-row; /* display like a table-row */
}
nav li ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a>First
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">I want this to wrap to the next line at 250px</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>Second
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"></a>Third
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

**Update (as per OP's comment regarding the need for a box-shadow)**

Assuming you're able to edit the HTML, you'll need to wrap the child ULs in an extra element.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/wtpvejjh/49/

Comment: I actually don't mean I want each individual page to have it's own width. I want the entire UL to expand with the longest text, up to 250px wide, and then wrap to the next line.

Comment: Awesome! This does what I want. The only problem I'm having now is that I have to set a drop-shadow on the ul, and setting a fixed width on it means when the text is shorter, you can still see the 250px wide box. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wtpvejjh/48/

Comment: @talena6 Its doable if you wrap the child ULs in a div. See my updates.

Answer (score 2):

***FIDDLE HERE*** http://jsfiddle.net/wtpvejjh/30/
.Check this i just played around with your bit of code and the solution was easy , actually you need to give max width to the `nav li ul li` not the `nav li ul` as you did.

***NOTE*** - Sometimes when you give max width and if a single word occupies greater width than the word comes out of the item, therefore use `word-wrap:break-word;` it will break the word and make it adjust the width.

Comment: Your fiddle actually doesn't work, it's narrower than mine. Thank you for trying!

Comment: i made it narrower purposely , you can increase the width

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. Yes I did see that, however if you do increase it to say 250px max-width, it wraps to the next line before reaching 250px.

Answer (score 0):

### for a smooth look  pseudo-elements are the answer

Giving the `nav ul` a fixed width and clearing it's elements float is correct.

Furthermore using `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements you'll give visual width coherency to the `nav li ul li` elements,

[**check out the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/wtpvejjh/46/).

Answer (score 0):

**Simply**, you just need to add the width property of your second level `li` to your css as follows:

```
nav ul li ul li{  
  width: 250px;
}
```

Checkout this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wtpvejjh/47/)

Comment: If you shorten the text, the width does not decrease with it.